# How to access member variable without using MACRO

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I delete my old question and reformulate the question here. Can I achieve following function using template instead?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define FUNC(T1, T2)  do {cout<< T1.T2<<endl; } while(0);

struct ST{
    double t1;
    int t2;
    double t3;
};

struct ST2{
    int t1;
    double h2;
};


int main()
{
    ST st;
    ST2 st2;
    st.t1 = 1.1;
    st.t2 = 0;
    st.t3 = 3.3;
    FUNC(st, t1);
    FUNC(st, t2);
    FUNC(st, t3);
    FUNC(st2, h2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do anything with that exact syntax. But you can get something close with member pointers and a function template:

```
template <typename T, typename Q>
void print(T& var, Q T::* mem)
{
    cout << var.*mem << endl;
}
```

Use:

```
print(st, &ST::t1);
print(st, &ST::t2);
print(st2, &ST2::h2);
```

<sub>Note that st2.h2 is uninitialized in your example, so your code exhibits undefined behavior.</sub>

Comment: My original intention is to get the address and type of particular member variable so that I can create another class to observe and update the variable (but not the whole class)

Comment: Well pointer-to-members sort of do that. You could store that pointer and a form of reference to the instance in a class. I don't really understand what you're trying to do, so hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I think I am good to go with your answer. I would like to boil down my question to the simplest one when I posted it on. But it also easily misleads people.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No.  But why would you want to?  What's so special about that `(`class variable`,` member`)` notation?  You can obviously write a function that takes `st.t1` instead of `st, t1` - why are you trying to avoid that?

Long answer: Not usefully.  `t1` is not in scope at the point you're calling `FUNC(st, t1)`... the current macro replaces it with `st.t1` which can be found in the current scope.  If you really *really* desparately wanted to hack something up, you'd have to put some kind of `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `h2` etc. objects in scope that could be passed to a function and somehow encoded which field should be accessed.  Having the local `t1` et al be pointers to the member variables is an obvious choice.  That would be pretty inconvenient, verbose and error-prone though: setting up all those extra variables just to support this indirection.

Comment: Sorry. My example may be oversimplified. My original intention is to get the address and type of particular member variable so that I can create another class to observe and update the variable (but not the whole class)

Comment: Then the kind of technique Mat's illustrated should help you: internally it can store suitable functors, or create a suitable type-specific template instantiation that you can dispatch to polymorphically from within your observation/update code....

Comment: Thanks for your help. I only try to simplify my question but I didn't make my intention clear.